# Contiguous Date Functionality: SAP HANA

Tags: sql, hana

We are trying to find continuous date from table

The expected output is attached in the image below:
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaz3d.png)

```
create column table "PS_CMP_TIME_ANALYTICS"."Temp2" (
"ID"  integer,
"Period"  date);

INSERT INTO "PS_CMP_TIME_ANALYTICS"."Temp2" VALUES (4, '2010-04-03');
INSERT INTO "PS_CMP_TIME_ANALYTICS"."Temp2" VALUES (5, '2010-04-07');
INSERT INTO "PS_CMP_TIME_ANALYTICS"."Temp2" VALUES (2, '2010-04-10');
INSERT INTO "PS_CMP_TIME_ANALYTICS"."Temp2" VALUES (3, '2010-04-15');
INSERT INTO "PS_CMP_TIME_ANALYTICS"."Temp2" VALUES (6, '2010-04-16');
INSERT INTO "PS_CMP_TIME_ANALYTICS"."Temp2" VALUES (7, '2010-04-17');
INSERT INTO "PS_CMP_TIME_ANALYTICS"."Temp2" VALUES (3, '2010-04-22');
INSERT INTO "PS_CMP_TIME_ANALYTICS"."Temp2" VALUES (4, '2010-04-24');
INSERT INTO "PS_CMP_TIME_ANALYTICS"."Temp2" VALUES (7, '2010-04-30');
INSERT INTO "PS_CMP_TIME_ANALYTICS"."Temp2" VALUES (2, '2010-05-01');
INSERT INTO "PS_CMP_TIME_ANALYTICS"."Temp2" VALUES (5, '2010-05-02');
INSERT INTO "PS_CMP_TIME_ANALYTICS"."Temp2" VALUES (3, '2010-05-03');
```

The query we tried in SAP HANA and output we are getting is mentioned below:

```
SELECT MIN("Period") AS BeginRange,
       MAX("Period") AS EndRange
FROM (
SELECT "Period",
    --DATEDIFF(D, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY "Period"), "Period") AS DtRange
cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY "Period") as date) as xyz,

    days_between(to_date(cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY "Period") as 
Date),'YYYY-MM-DD'), "Period") AS DtRange
FROM "PS_CMP_TIME_ANALYTICS"."Temp2") AS dt
GROUP BY DtRange;
```

But we are not getting the output as expected find the attached out we got using SAP HANA SQL The END date should be changed
[Our Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsmyo.png)

How can we achieve in SAP HANA SQL

Comment: It is not completely clear to me what you want to achieve. Do you merely want to find maximally spanning date intervals (i.e. intervals for which all the spanned consecutive dates are present in the table). Does the ID column have any effect? It does not seem to be unique. How about the "period" column? Can it contain duplicate values?

Answer (score 0):

You Can below Code in SAP HANA

```
SELECT MIN("Period") as "Start_Date",MAX("Period") as "End_Date",
(days_between(Min("Period"),Max("Period")) + 1) as "Days"
FROM
(select "Period",add_days("Period" ,- ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY "Period"))rn
from "SchemaName"."Temp2")
GROUP BY rn
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are looking for upper bound of data islands in your ordered table columns which is similar to finding lower limits of gaps

An other solution can be following SQLScript where I used [SQL LEAD() function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/lead-function-in-sql-server-2012-for-next-value.aspx) to calculate the next value in date field

```
with cte as (
    select
    "ID", "Period", LEAD("Period", 1) over (order by "Period") NextDate
    from "Temp2"
)
select "ID", "Period"
from cte
where IFNULL(DAYS_BETWEEN("Period",NextDate),9) > 1
```

I also used [SQL CTE expressions](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=18) which might me a new syntax for many HANA developers coming from ABAP programming experience.
But I use it a lot and is especially more powerful with multiple CTE in single SELECT statements.

Output is as follows for the above SQLScript query

[image]